# What is the Alert Manager alert rule for notifying about Docker container restarting?

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to add an alert rule that would allow Alert Manager to notify me whenever a particular docker container restarts. Does such rule exist? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to see the number of seconds that have passed since the container was started.

```
 time() - container_start_time_seconds
```

Comment: Sweet! Will try it! Thanks!

Comment: tried this method but it just alerts on everything. I tried specifying the container name like so: time() - container_start_time_seconds{container_name}, but it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to make it work with process_start_time_seconds{job='my_job'} expression